# JsonPropertyOrder doesnt work with javax rs response

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jersey-2.0, jackson2

I am trying to order elements for response json using JsonPropertyOrder annotation  but Json property is not been ordered in response json. I tried keeping index in json property annotation that also didnt help . I am passing the object to javax.ws.rs.core.ResponseBuilder.entity. Could some one please help on this

rest service response some thing like below

```
 @GET

    @Path("/test/output")

    public Response getOffers()
    {

          return Response.status(200)
.entity(new ExtInstallResponse("testId","testVersion","testName"))
.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

    }
```

POJO as below :

```
   @JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "id", "version"})
    public class ExtInstallResponse {

      @JsonProperty("id")
      private String id;

      @JsonProperty("version")
      private String version;

      @JsonProperty("name")
      private String name;

      /**
       * constructor.
       *
       * @param id id
       * @param version version
       * @param name name
       */
      public ExtInstallResponse(String id, String version, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String getVersion() {
        return version;
      }

      public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
      }
    }
```

I am getting response in below format but I need it to be orderd as name, id,version

```
{
    "id": "ExtensionId3",
    "name": "Extension Id 3",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

same works fine when I try from java main method

Comment: Are you sure you are using Jackson as your JSON provider? If you have others on the classpath, it will not default to using Jackson

Comment: but @Jsonproperty works well when I change field name  json response is coming with property used in jsonproperty. if we think its using others it should also not work right